# Max value using define

Tags: c

The task is to take input from the user for 5 integers and using the `#define`
directive, find the maximum value. Now, I've used the define directive for defining constants, even smaller functions but can't understand the logic behind this. Should I define my function or perform the whole task in the `#define`?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define LARGEST(y) ((y[0]>y[1])?y[0]:y[1])
int main()
{
    int i,y;
    int x[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("Enter the value of X:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);}    
    int a=LARGEST(x);
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

This is my code for the program. Any explanation or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not calculate the largest number in the loop where the input is entered? You don't even need an array to store every number.

Comment: this macro isn't really useful because elements must be in an array. all 3 last elements are ignored by your code.

Comment: Don't have much experience with arrays, figured I should try to take multiple inputs like this.
Can't figure the logic for considering other values.

Comment: The *assignment* in itself doesn't make much sense. Ask the one who assigned you this task.

Comment: You are making this harder than it needs to be. You can either take user input and begin using your comparison on the second input and save the larger value with each new input, or if you want to use an array, store all values in the array, and then loop over all values calling your `LARGEST` macro saving the largest in a variable each time --- your choice.

Comment: An array is not really necessary, I could just initialize four variables but need to figure out the largest value using define.

Comment: Don't use macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search for the maximum could be done on the fly as follows; neither the macro nor the program itself would need an array for this.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <limits.h>
#define LARGEST(x,y) ( (x) > (y) ? (x) : (y) )
int main()
{
    int a = INT_MIN;
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        int x = 0;
        printf("Enter the value of X:\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        a = LARGEST(x, a);
    }    
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

The macro uses the ternary operator to evaluate to the larger of its arguments. In the program itself, only a local variable for the current input and the current maximum are used; the maximum is initialized to the smallest value possible.

Comment: @EdHeal I think so; however the OP explicitly demanded for a macro.

Comment: Could you explain me parts of your code? 
- Why is the limits.h included?
-The variable a? Is it a function or what?

Comment: @Hasan `limits.h` is included for the `INT_MIN` constant. The variable `a` is meant to contain the current maximum. The macro uses the [? operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C) to yield the maximum of its arguments.

Comment: What will be the value of y/a for the first time the macro is called?

Comment: The first values will we `x` (initialized from the user's input) and `a = INT_MIN`, the smallest number representable with `int`. This initialization is do circumvent an awkward initialization with the first input.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, you can either check for the largest each time input is taken, or you can store all input in an array and then loop over each value in the array. The first approach is much simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5
#define LARGEST(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

int main (void)
{
    int largest = 0, n = 0, x;

    while (n < MAX) {
        int ret;
        printf ("enter value %d of %d: ", n + 1, MAX);
        ret = scanf ("%d", &x); /* validate conversion */
        if (ret == 1) {         /* input is valid */
            if (n)              /* not the first value */
                largest = LARGEST(largest,x);
            n++;
        }
        else if (ret == EOF) {  /* always check EOF */
            fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else {          /* input was not an integer */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            int c;      /* flush stdin to avoid loop */
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        }
    }

    printf ("\nlargest: %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Never used the 'fprintf' function, can I skip the parts in the else? Or if you could just elaborate a bit. I would appreciate it!

Comment: Well, no. You do not want to skip *any* validation steps when taking user input. (technically you can -- but it is bad practice, for all you know a cat may be stepping on the keyboard). `fprintf` is the same as `printf` except it writes to a file. Above it is writing to `stderr` (where `printf` simply writes to `stdout`. (your 3 standard file streams: `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`). When you write error messages, they should be written to `stderr` to allow segregation of program output and errors. Take the time to allow it all to sink in. C takes understanding every character.

Comment: The difference between the code above and the code without the validation of input becomes immediately apparent if something other than an integer is entered or the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF` (`ctrl+d` on nix'es, `ctrl+z` on windoze). Give both versions a try and see which allows you to actually recover and enter 5 values.